# How to calculate area of a polygon with latitude and longitude?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have the following method that checks whether is `points` are polygon

```
from shapely import wkt

def validate_polygon(points):
    try:
        wkt.loads("POLYGON((%s))" % points)
    except Exception as ex:
        raise WrongRequestDataError("Incorrect points format. " + str(ex))
```

How can I calculate area of the `polygon` and throw exception if it's greater than 400 square miles?

I have tried to check this:

```
polygon = wkt.loads("POLYGON((%s))" % "34.093523 -118.274893,34.091414 -118.275887,34.092082 -118.278062,34.093867 -118.276609,34.093523 -118.274893")
print(polygon.area)

4.406979500001112e-06
```

but it seems like the incorrect answer or what type of units it uses for this value and how to translate it to square miles or km^2?

Answer (score 5):

typically you would compute the area like this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
points = [(34.093523, -118.274893), (34.091414, -118.275887), (34.092082, -118.278062), (34.093867, -118.276609), (34.093523, -118.274893)]
polygon = Polygon(points)
# the area in square degrees
area_sdeg = polygon.area
```

note: for area calculation in square meters, you have to use projections as described in https://gist.github.com/robinkraft/c6de2f988c9d3f01af3c

Comment: Are you sure? This value are super big  `polygon.area*earth_radius_miles**2`!

Comment: I was wrong regarding area calculation. polygon.area returns square degrees... you have to use projections for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution that works perfectly for me

```
def compute_polygon_area(points):
    coordinates = (tuple(map(float, x.split())) for x in points.split(', '))
    xy_coordinates = switch_to_xy_coordinates(coordinates)
    return Polygon(xy_coordinates).area

def switch_to_xy_coordinates(coordinates):
    earth_radius = 6371  # in km
    lat_dist = pi * earth_radius / 180.0

    latitudes, longitudes = zip(*coordinates)
    y = (lat * lat_dist for lat in latitudes)
    x = (lon * lat_dist * cos(radians(lat))
     for lat, lon in zip(latitudes, longitudes))
    return list(zip(x, y))
```

Comment: The OP is probably looking for the area of the rectangle on the surface of the earth. Not the area of the rectangle that cuts through the surface.